# Trace-maximizing orthogonal rotation

Tags: matrices, optimization, trace, orthogonal-matrices, procrustes-problem

Let $A\in R^{m\times m}$. Consider the following problem:

$$
\begin{align}
\max \,& \langle A,  X\rangle\\
\text{s.t.}\,&X'X=I_m\\
&X\in R^{m\times m}
\end{align}
$$
where $\langle X, Y\rangle =\text{trace}(X'Y)$. This is not a convex problem. Is there an analytical solution for it, or an algorithm?

Comment: You wrote $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times\color{red}{A}}$. Did you mean $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times\color{red}{m}}$? If so, this is a standard problem. Let $A=USV^T$ be a singular value decomposition. Then $X=UV^T$ is a maximiser.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't see why is $\text{trace}(S)$ necessarily the maximum of the problem. Could you add a few words on this?

Comment: You need a scalar value to optimize. Trace is analytically solvable as opposed to let's say induced 2-norm of a matrix, while still being a meaningful measure for optimization.

Comment: @user1551 That gives you the best orthogonal matrix, but in order to make sure that $X$ is a rotation there's an additional step

Comment: @gappy Note that maximizing $\langle X,A \rangle$ is equivalent to minimizing $m + \langle A,A\rangle - 2\langle X,A \rangle = \|X-A\|^2$, which means that this is equivalent to [Wabha's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahba%27s_problem).